# Why AudioInputStream read never returns -1?

Tags: java, stream, microphone, javasound

I'm reading an `AudioInputStream` and using it to make a chunked POST request to a server in order to stream audio. I don't understand why `read()` method on the stream always returns 0, also after having called `stop()` and `close()` on `TargetDataLine`. I'm expecting at some point to have -1 since the stream is closed and there is no more data on it (EOF). This is causing me problems in Apache HTTP Client call that is making the POST, because at some point it expects -1 to terminate writing the output stream and in this way never terminates the write loop.

Here is the snippet:

```
public class MicrophoneTest {

// record duration, in milliseconds
static final long RECORD_TIME = 5000;

private static AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(48000, 16, 1, true, false);

public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
    final Microphone recorder = new Microphone(audioFormat);

    recorder.open();

    // creates a new thread that waits for a specified
    // of time before stopping
    Thread stopper = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(RECORD_TIME);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            recorder.close();
        }
    });

    stopper.start();

    // start recording
    AudioInputStream inputStream = recorder.start();

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
    int read = -1;
    while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        System.out.println(read);
        outputStream.write(buffer);
    }   

    // Never gets here!
}   
}



public class Microphone {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Microphone.class);

// format of audio file
private static final AudioFileFormat.Type fileType = AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE;

// the line from which audio data is captured
private TargetDataLine line;

private AudioFormat audioFormat;

public Microphone(AudioFormat audioFormat) {
    this.audioFormat = audioFormat;
}

/**
 * Prepare the line for recording
 * 
 * @return
 */
public boolean open() {
    try {
        Info info = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo()[4];
        line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getTargetDataLine(audioFormat, info);
        line.open(audioFormat);

    } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
        LOGGER.error(ex.toString(), ex);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Captures the sound and return the stream
 */
public AudioInputStream start() {

    if (line != null) {

        line.start(); // start capturing

        LOGGER.info("Start recording...");

        return new AudioInputStream(line);

        // AudioSystem.write(ais, fileType, outputStream);

    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Line has not created. Cannot start recording");
    }
}

/**
 * Stops the recording process
 */
public void stop() {
    line.stop();
    LOGGER.info("Stop recording...");
}

/**
 * Closes the target data line to finish capturing and recording     * 
 */
public void close() {
    line.stop();
    line.close();
    LOGGER.info("Data line closed");
}
}
```

Comment: Does it really return zero? It's only supposed to do that if the buffer is zero length.

Comment: It returns 0 when I close the TargetDataLine

Comment: Well that's a bug. It should return -1. But all it means to you is that you should loop on `> 0` instead of `!= -1`. Or provide a `FilterInputStream` that fixes the buf.

Comment: Thanks, I've solved using FilterInputStream. If you post as a response I will put as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The microphone line never reaches the end of a file. It is either on or off. It is not reading a file from a disk or memory location.

I think you need to change your while loop to something like the following:

```
while(isRecording)
{
    read = inputStream.read(buffer);
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
}
```

and have your stop() method include

```
isRecording = false;
```

and your start() method include

```
isRecording = true;
```

etc. That sort of thing.

Comment: What do you suggest to pass the InputStream to ApacheHttp? It expects an InputStream that a some point returns -1 (EOF).

Comment: If the receiving code can not be rewritten as suggested, maybe use the Microphone-derived input stream as a source for a new InputStream (Adapter pattern?). Then, when you turn off the spigot, you can code in a -1 as the last element.